# Angular/TypeScript: how to initialize Observable matrix

Tags: angular, typescript, matrix, observable

On Angular I write in the html template this code:

```
<div *ngFor='let itemArray of myObservableArray'>
  <div *ngFor='let item of itemArray | async'>
    {{item.value}}
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService, MyDataType } from './app.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  myObservableArray: Observable<MyDataType[][]>;

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    this.getData(2);
  }

  getData(id: number) {
    if (!this.myObservableArray) {
      this.myObservableArray = new Array<MyDataType[]>();
      this.myObservableArray[id] = this.myService.getData(id);
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the code of the app.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  mydata: MyDataType[] = [
    {"id":1, "value":"value_1_1"},
    {"id":1, "value":"value_1_2"},
    {"id":2, "value":"value_2_1"},
    {"id":2, "value":"value_2_2"},
    {"id":3, "value":"value_3_1"},
    {"id":3, "value":"value_3_2"}
  ];

  constructor() { }

  getData(id: number):Observable<MyDataType[]>
  {
    let data = new Observable<MyDataType[]>(observer => {

          setTimeout(() => {
              observer.next(this.mydata.filter(i => i.id == id));
          }, 4000);
    });
    return data;
  }
}

export class MyDataType
{
  public id: number;
  public value: string;
}
```

The html template works correctly but I don't understand why the compiler give me this error:

```
Type 'MyDataType[][]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<MyDataType[][]>'.
      Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'MyDataType[][]'.
    (property) AppComponent.myObservableArray: Observable<MyDataType[][]>
```

I think my initialization of the matrix is wrong but being quite new on Angular and TypeScript/JavaScript I would like help on how I can do it.
On stackbliz I put the complete [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngfor-with-observable-matrix). Thanks.

Comment: probably because you declare `myObservableArray: Observable<MyDataType[][]>;` but then use `this.myObservableArray = new Array<MyDataType[]>();`

Comment: @mast3rd3mon your comment does not help me. Could you tell me how I should initialize it if you know?

Comment: im pretty sure theres an `ObservableArray` which would be used as `myObservableArray: ObservableArray<MyDataType[]>;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem declaring:

```
myObservableArray: Observable<Array<MyDataType[]>> = new Observable<Array<MyDataType[]>>();
```

and changing the `getData` method like the following:

```
getData(id: number) {
  if (!this.myObservableArray[id]) {
      this.myObservableArray[id] = this.myService.getData(id);
  }
}
```

and the html template in this way:

```
<div *ngFor='let item of myObservableArray[2]| async'>
    {{item.value}}
</div>
```

I have update the [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngfor-with-observable-matrix)

Answer (score 0):

I've forked your stackblitz and simplified your solution. Check out [Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngfor-with-observable-matrix-fwjmva)

app.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { interval } from 'rxjs/observable/interval';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  mydata: MyDataType[] = [
    {"id":1, "value":"value_1_1"},
    {"id":1, "value":"value_1_2"},
    {"id":2, "value":"value_2_1"},
    {"id":2, "value":"value_2_2"},
    {"id":3, "value":"value_3_1"},
    {"id":3, "value":"value_3_2"}
  ];

  constructor() { }

  // use interval with map instead of setTimeout
  getData(id: number): Observable<MyDataType[]> {
    return interval(5000).pipe(map(i =>this.mydata.filter(i => i.id == id)))
  }
}
```

app.component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService, MyDataType } from './app.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  myObservableArray: Observable<MyDataType[]>;

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    this.getData(2);
  }

  getData(id: number) {
    // you do not needed nested arrays here
    this.myObservableArray = this.myService.getData(id);
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<p>
    Wait 5 seconds to see some magic happen :)
</p>

<div *ngFor='let item of myObservableArray | async'>
    {{item.value}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but you declare `myObservableArray: Observable<MyDataType[]>;` and this is an array, not a matrix, and isn't what I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService, MyDataType } from './app.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
```

Here you declare myObservableArray as

```
Observable<MyDataType[][]
```

.

```
  myObservableArray: Observable<MyDataType[][]>;

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    this.getData(2);
  }

  getData(id: number) {
    if (!this.myObservableArray) {
```

But then you try to put

```
Array<MyDataType[]>()
```

into it.

```
      this.myObservableArray = new Array<MyDataType[]>();
      this.myObservableArray[id] = this.myService.getData(id);
    }
  }
}
```

You can't put an

```
Array<MyDataType[]>
```

into an

```
Observable<MyDataType[][]
```

This is what the compiler is trying to tell you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Finally I solved the problem declaring:
`myObservableArray: Observable<Array<MyDataType[]>> = new Observable<Array<MyDataType[]>>()` and adapting the code.

Comment: Glad to hear that. It was a nice gesture if you would mark this post as solution, though.  :)